# formal explanation/proof of an intuitive fact

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

If we know that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)<\sum_{k=1}^{n} g(k)$ then we also know that for at least one $k$, $g(k)>f(k)$ holds. My idea to explain this would be: Let's assume the contrary so that $g(k)\leq f(k)$ holds for every $k$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k) \geq \sum_{k=1}^{n} g(k)$ follows and we arrive at a contradiction! Therefore $g(k)>f(k)$ holds for at least one $k$. 
Is this correct?

Comment: The negation of $x>y$ is $x \leq y$.

Comment: I think your argument is correct. My personal intuition was to divide both sums in the first inequality by n because that would give the average of the each sum. But it’s the same thing at the end of the day

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer!

Comment: You don't need to use contradiction here, what you've written is a proof by contrapositive.